# Using Hibernate Restrictions.in with a List<enum>

Tags: hibernate

How do I use Restrictions.in with an field that is a List?

Here is my model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "W_GROUP", schema = "U_FRONTEND")
public class UserGroup {
@Id
@Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "NAME", length = 100, nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;

@ElementCollection(targetClass = Feature.class)
@JoinTable(name = "W_FEATURE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", nullable = false), schema = "U_FRONTEND")
@Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private List<Feature> features;

@JoinTable(name = "W_USER_GROUP", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"), schema = "U_FRONTEND")
@ManyToMany
private List<User> users;

@Column(name = "UPD_USER", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String updUser;

@Column(name = "UPD_DATE", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "date")
private Calendar updDate;
// Getters and setters
}
```

I'm trying to get only the groups that have some Features:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserGroup.class);

            criteria.addOrder(new Sort(Order.ASC, "name").getOrder());

            criteria.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("features",
                    FeatureUtils.getInvalids())));
```

But this returns an error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Missing IN or
>   OUT parameter at index:: 1    at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
>     at $Proxy35.executeQuery(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1926)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1727)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:852)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:293)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2411)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2397)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2227)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2222)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:122)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1621)   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)   at
>   hamburgsud.frontend.dao.UserGroupDAO.list(UserGroupDAO.java:39)   at
>   hamburgsud.frontend.controller.UserController.form(UserController.java:38)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExecuteMethodInterceptor.intercept(ExecuteMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>     ... 43 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT
>   parameter at index:: 1    at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:1681)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3280)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3329)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
>     ... 63 more

Comment: I think I have the same problem. Hibernate doesn't seem to be able to work well with Enums in Restrictions

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not very pretty, but you could construct a list of ids (`List<Long> featureIds`) and then do a:

```
Restrictions.in("features", featureIds);
```

Comment: But Feature is an Enum:
public enum Feature {
 LOGGED_OFF, LOGGED_IN, USER_MAINTENANCE, COMPASS_MAINTENANCE, MASTERFILE_MAINTENANCE, SELLER_CABOTAGE, SELLER_DEEP_SEA, SELLER_MAINTENANCE, PARAMETER_MAINTENANCE, COORDINATOR_MAINTENANCE, COORDINATOR, BUDGET_TRUST_REPORT_MAINTENANCE, IMPORT_CUSTOMERS, VISITOR;

 public String getLabel() {
  return this.name().toLowerCase().replace("_", "-");
 }
}